# Change default date time format on a single database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I need to change the date format from US (mm/dd/YYYY) to UK (dd/mm/YYYY) on a single database on a SQL server machine.

How can this be done?

I've seen statements that do this for the whole system, and ones that do it for the session, but I can't change the code now as it will have to go through QA again, so I need a quick fix to change the date time format.

**Update**

I realize that the date time has nothing to do with how SQL Server stores the data, but it does have a lot to do with how it parses queries.

I'm chucking raw data from an XML file into a database. The dates in the XML file are in UK date format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use **SET DATEFORMAT**, like in this example

```
declare @dates table (orig varchar(50) ,parsed datetime)

SET DATEFORMAT ydm;

insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

select * from @dates
```

You would need to specify the dateformat in the code when you parse your XML data

Comment: @Y. Ecarri - so how to change DATABASE date (not datetime) format? In my SQL server the format is yyyy-mm-dd however I need mm/dd/yyyy permanently. Please help.

Answer (score 13):

In order to avoid dealing with these very boring issues, I advise you to always parse your data with the **standard and unique SQL/ISO date format** which is YYYY-MM-DD. Your queries will then work internationally, no matter what the date parameters are on your main server or on the querying clients (where local date settings might be different than main server settings)!

Comment: unfortunately I'm not generating the data just consumung it.

Comment: Philippe - I was convinced about that as well until someone showed me an example in SQL Server 2008 when date specified as 2008-09-01 was translated to 9th of January 2008 when the region was set to US.

Comment: As a rule I am trying to avoid using date in string format on the database level. When dealing with data input I would cast the string to date on the application level using appropriate locale settings so then it reaches the db in datetime date type. This way it is independent on the local settings

Comment: I've marked this as useful as it helped me, although it didn't really solve Omar's problem.  However I would be interested to see Kristof's example where it fails - surely if it fails to parse the ISO format correctly in all cases, regardless of server configuration, that's a bug?!  (I realise this is a very old question, so I don't hold out much hope of an example...)

Comment: The correct way of writing a date in a format independent of locale settings in SQL server is `YYYYMMDD` (not `YYYY-MM-DD`), see [KB173907](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907) (quote: *A possible solution to this is to use the ISO Standard format for sending the datetime data to SQL Server, which is "YYYYMMDD" (no separators).*)

Answer (score 6):

You can only change the language on the whole server, not individual databases.  However if you need to support the UK you can run the following command before all inputs and outputs:

```
set language 'british english'
```

Or if you are having issues entering datatimes from your application you might want to consider a universal input type such as

> 1-Dec-2008

Comment: How does one change the language ont he server then?

Answer (score 5):

Although you can not set the default date format for a single database, you can change the default language for a login which is used to access this database:

```
ALTER LOGIN your_login WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=British
```

In some cases it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this really is a QA issue and you can't change the code.  Setup a new server instance on the machine and setup the language as "British English"

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that format has nothing to do with how SQL Server stores datetime, right?

You can use `set dateformat` for each session. There is no setting for database only.

If you use parameters for data insert or update or where filtering you won't have any problems with that.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
select * from mytest
EXEC sp_rename 'mytest.eid', 'id', 'COLUMN'
alter table mytest add id int not null identity(1,1)
update mytset set eid=id
ALTER TABLE mytest DROP COLUMN eid

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yourtablename] ADD DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [yourfieldname]
```

It's working 100%.

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server 2008 run:

```
EXEC sp_defaultlanguage 'username', 'british'
```