# how to change datetime format for the whole database?

Tags: sql-server-2005

My application is based on format: mm/dd/yyyy

After deploying the database to the customer's side, it is based on: dd/mm/yyyy

I dont want to change all of my queries, so how can I change all the datetime format for the whole database?

It is MSSQL Server 2005

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "based on format ..."? You're storing dates as strings?

Comment: You don't need to change the DB then. And in your application (written in what language?), you're using a DateTime as well?

Comment: how can I select my current date time format of the server?

Comment: I select in my query: DateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: How are you building your queries? Using parameters (good)? Or concatenating strings (bad)?

Comment: Use the standard ISO-8601 format in your code: `YYYYMMDD` - this format will **always** work, regardless of what date format is set up on the customer's SQL Server installation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look at :[Change default date time format on a single database in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/change-default-date-time-format-on-a-single-database-in-sql-server)

If question is related with SQL server only, it should be closed. If no, it should be moved to C# topic.

Comment: how to check my current dateFormat then I can compare from my server and their server? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to you could write a class which would interoperate the date() function (which produces a timestamp) into a real date, which you could then insert into the database.

But you should be more specific, ie, what languages are you using to code in, if you are, etc?

Comment: I'm not familier with C# directly, however this link may help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the default language for the database and then change the default language for all of your logins.  I have a blog that explains this:
[Setting a standard date format](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se)