# Changing SQL Server 2005 date format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I change the date format setting in SQL Server 2005 from `dd/mm/yyyy` format to `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/change-default-date-time-format-on-a-single-database-in-sql-server  Setting the language to "British English" might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague - in what context do you want the change the date? In a query? If so, use the SQL below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(),126) --result: 2012-01-24
```

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on `CAST` and `CONVERT` for additional information.

**Update After Clarification**

Please refer to this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;173907

Comment: Thanks you for responding, i don't want to cast nor convert. i want to change the setting/option/configuration on my SQL express 2005 to format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) command.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ydm;
GO
DECLARE @datevar DATETIME;
SET @datevar = '1998/31/12';
SELECT @datevar AS DateVar;
GO
-- Result: 1998-12-31 00:00:00.000
```