# How to display the date as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm Am/PM using sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

My sample query is

```
SELECT D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y
from CSPGD30_TRACKING D30
```

My given date format is like `"2013-01-01 00:00:00.000"`. I need to convert this date format to `"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"`. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Is your current column of datetime format?

Comment: @ashreva, yes my current column is date time format. Do you have any idea about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/change-default-date-time-format-on-a-single-database-in-sql-server

Comment: @KasperVesth: what duplicate you find it ??. OP ask for `datetime` with `AM/PM` format. I dnt see AM/PM format in the link you provided

Comment: @Satindersingh The post I linked to talks about changing the date time format in general by specifying what culture you are using.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think there is no single format to give them both. Try this using `Convert`; [Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9309)

```
declare @mydate datetime = getdate()
select convert(varchar(10),@mydate, 101) + right(convert(varchar(32),@mydate,100),8)

|           COLUMN_0 |
----------------------
| 02/22/2013  9:36AM |
```

Comment: This does work @SHOHILSETHIA. What version of SQL server are you on?

Answer (score 39):

The FORMAT() function is available from version 2012 onwards.
Once upgraded, you can use

```sql
select FORMAT(@date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt')
```

Comment: Not in SQL Server 2008 R2 - The Format function isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mydate, 101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, mydate, 100), 7) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT convert(varchar(20), GetDate(), 0);
```

To extract only AM/PM

```
substring(convert(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/1188)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following scenario for getting date,time,day,month,year,hours,minutes,seconds,AM/PM

:)

```
SELECT UpdatedOn ,
  CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100) DateTime,
  CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,10) Date ,
  CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108) Time ,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),1,2) Day,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),4,3) CMonth,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,105),4,2) NMonth,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),8,4) Year,
  left(right(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100),7),2) Hours_12,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),1,2) Hours_24,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),4,2) Minutes,
  substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),7,2) Second,
  right(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100),2) AM_PM 
FROM dbo.DeviceAssignSim 
WHERE AssignSimId=55;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's not a great solution due to it's lack of brevity. Other answers are both more concise and answer the question.

Comment: there are simpler solution to this - how am I supposed to use it in a big query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

For more information look this:

[date-format](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: if i use this format it shows only the "01/01/2013". In addtion to that i need the "01/01/2013 12:23 PM"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `convert` method to format a `datetime` value. Example:

```
select convert(varchar(20), D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y, 101)
```

The third parameter determines the format. You can find the available formats in the [cast and convert documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your rpely, but it showing this format "01/01/2013"

Comment: @Adalarasan_Serangulam: Yes, check the documentation for the available formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Select (Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),101))+' '+(Right(('0'+(LTrim((Left((Right((Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),100)),7)),5))))),5))+' '+(Right((Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),100)),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a 8 year old question but it was answered in many ways and none are simple enough. This is what I found to be simple and matches just about what the user is asking for (year is two digits, and seconds are present), assuming that the date he is getting is from GETDATE(), not that it matters but that is where my answer comes from.

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar, D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y, 22) AS [DateTime]`

```
12/16/20 10:19:18 AM
```

Comment: On 2008R2, I just tested this and noted that replacing the source column  (D30.SPGD30_LAST_TOUCH_Y above) with GETDATE() works.  Replacing it with a date string causes the AM/PM to get cut off.   Same thing happened for the accepted answer.  Probably would need an additional convert to datetime for the source string to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query which will give AM and PM as well.
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt') AS requestedDateFormat;