# MSSQL / ASP Date Format UK Datetime issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

This is quite complicated to explain so I apologise in advance. I am in the UK so this is in relation to datetime format for the UK.

I have a VBS that is submitting to an ASP page which then inserts into an SQL Database with a datetime field.

- The VBS Submits as: 05/07/2013 05:04:12
- The ASP Processes as: 05/07/2013 05:04:12
- This displays in MSSQL as: 2013-07-05 05:04:12.000

The problem is that my format in MSSQL should be YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.000 - it has inserted above as YYYY-DD-MM HH-MM-SS.000

This is causing huge problems when I am processing these dates because it thinks the date is in the future. Interestingly it only seems to occur on certain dates (I suspect this happens when the day number is higher than 12 and it knows the month can't be 13 so formats it properly.

How can I set this permanently to avoid SQL inserting the dates the wrong way round? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some code please

Comment: The problem isn't really down at the SQL Server level - it's that you're treating this as a string for far too long - you need to, as soon as is practicable, convert it to a real date/time object (using e.g. `CDate`) and then *keep* it as a datetime all down through the stack and into the database.

Comment: can more explanation ?

Comment: Damien - tried this as I thought it sounded most logical - converted to a date object using cdate as soon as the variable was submitted but it made no different it still inserted into the database in the wrong format.

Comment: The thing is, Dates in the database (in `datetime` columns) don't *have* a format. Internally, they're stored as a special floating point number. So any formatting issues are arising somewhere in the *string* handling portions of your code.

Comment: Thanks Damien - that does help. Further testing has revealed that it's changing the date format as it is being submitted before it even hits the ASP page so will repost a different question for VBS. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use SET DATEFORMAT, like in this example

```
declare @dates table (orig varchar(50) ,parsed datetime)

SET DATEFORMAT ydm;

insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

select * from @dates
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/change-default-date-time-format-on-a-single-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the ISO format in SQL Server statements. I have written a function for this purpose.

```
function getIsoTimestamp(dt_in, s_time_zone, n_options)
        ' time zone format examples: "" = local time; "Z" = Zulu time/UTC, "+0100" = MEZ/CET
        ' options:
        '   1: remove time information
        '   2: remove date delimiter char
        '   4: remove time delimiter char
        dim s_out, s_year, s_month, s_day, s_hour, s_min, s_sec
        dim s_date_delim, s_time_delim

        s_out = ""

        if isDate(dt_in) then
                s_date_delim = iff((n_options AND 2)=2, "", "-")
                s_time_delim = iff((n_options AND 4)=4, "", ":")

                ' format date
                s_year = year(dt_in)
                s_month = Right(100 + month(dt_in), 2)
                s_day = Right(100 + day(dt_in), 2)
                s_out = s_year & s_date_delim & s_month & s_date_delim & s_day

                ' format time
                if (n_options AND 1)=0 then
                        s_hour = Right(100 + hour(dt_in), 2)
                        s_min = Right(100 + minute(dt_in), 2)
                        s_sec = Right(100 + second(dt_in), 2)
                        s_out = s_out & "T" & s_hour & s_time_delim & s_min & s_time_delim & s_sec & s_time_zone
                end if
        end if

        getIsoTimestamp = s_out
end function
```

You can use `getIsoTimestamp(now(), "", 0)` to test it.