# SQL Server Convert datetime to mm/dd/yyyy format but still be a datetime datatype

Tags: sql-server

I would like to keep my dates as `datetime` datatype by also be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. I know how to do this by converting them to a `varchar`, but want to keep the `datetime` format. Can anyone help with this?

Currently I have tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 101)
```

which is not working...

Comment: You have to change a server setting, which has its own consequences.  But, this is probably a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/change-default-date-time-format-on-a-single-database-in-sql-server

Comment: format is a concept bound to the presentation layer; a date information has no format. if you expect a format for date information in your database you are misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a basic misunderstanding in your question. Repeat after me: **Datetimes don't have a format.**

It helps if you think of them as just an array of seven integers (year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) with certain constraints. That's not in any way accurate, but it helps to get the notion out of your head that something akin to `12/31/2015` is stored in your database.

Datetimes only get a format when (implicitly or explicitly) being converted to strings. You already know how to set the format when explicitly converting to string, now all that is left to do is to find the *implicit* conversion that is obviously bothering you and replace it with an explicit one.

Comment: "Datetimes don't have a format" :) I just want to make sure that i am also understanding you correctly. Is what i am looking for not obtainable?

Comment: @scapegoat17 What you want *is* attainable, but misguided.  It is important to understand why you want it, and then decide if it is really necessary.  Why do you want the "format" to be MM/DD/YYYY and yet still be a datetime?  In any scenario that matters, the "format" of the value is irrelevant.

Comment: personally it is not something that i want, but I was asked for it and i am just trying to see how it is possible. Do you know?

Comment: @scapegoat17: Correct, it is not obtainable. Today's date is *always* stored as `(2015, 07, 16, 00, 00, 00, 00)` (or rather: the number of seconds since the beginning of the epoch, but that's a technical detail) with no notion of a format. You *can* change the default format used by SQL Server for implicit conversions, but that's a global setting and has no effect on the storage of datetime values.

Answer (score 0):

Date and datetime Values stored in the database are NOT in any recognizable format. They are stored in binary (1s and 0s) in a proprietary format where one part represents the number of days since a defined reference date (1 jan 1900) in SQL server). and the other part represents the time portion of the value. (in sql server, its the number of 1/300ths of a second since midnight.)

ALL formatting of dates and date times, no matter what format you wish for, is done only *after* the values have been extracted from the database, before you see them on screen, in whatever application you are using.

You can find all the formats that the SQL Server convert function can use on this [MSDN Convert Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)